# Crunchbase by country

Tags: api

I originally posted this on the Crunchbase Google group but got no replies, so I'm trying here. I know that normally posting to a bunch of different forums with the same thing is a no-no, but I honestly did try.

Now on to my problem.

I've been noodling around with the Crunchbase API for a research project, and am trying to get a complete company list (w/details) of companies in Canada. Here are a few examples of variations that I have tried:

```
http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/search.js?api_key=<key>&geo=canada&range=10000
```

...returns 9 results. There are definitely more than that.

```
http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/search.js?api_key=<key>&geo=CAN&range=100000
```

...returns 46 results, in Hungary, Romania, etc.

I've also tried other variations but not really getting any further.

So I am sure there is a simple way to get Canadian companies but I'm obviously not getting it.

Can someone suggest the best parameters to get Canada and only Canada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer (thanks Vineet Thanedar) by the developer is posted here:

```
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/crunchbase-api/OK8WjUcQltQ
```

In the end, because I needed to actually be pretty thorough, I built a json call that checked all ~115K+ permalinks, looking for Canadian offices and only returned data for the companies that met that criteria. It was a bit of a shotgun approach, and not something I'm going to use very frequently, but it worked. For a 'by city' approach, I'll definitely be referencing the guidance posted to the Google group.